# Why all these macro type definitions in glibc?

Tags: c

Let's take the following examples for `LIST_HEAD` and `LIST_ENTRY` in [queue.h in glibc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/misc/sys/queue.h.html):

```
/*
 * List definitions.
 */
#define        LIST_HEAD(name, type)                                                \
struct name {                                                                \
        struct type *lh_first;        /* first element */                        \
}
#define        LIST_ENTRY(type)                                                \
struct {                                                                \
        struct type *le_next;        /* next element */                        \
        struct type **le_prev;        /* address of previous next element */        \
}
```

[image]

Why are these all defined as macros? It seems whenever I ask a question about macros the answer/comments are somewhere along the lines of "Don't abuse the preprocessor" and yet here in glibc they have entire files defined that are nothing but extremely complicated macros.

Comment: I think this is a primitive way of implementing templates to C.

Comment: *"and yet here in glibc they have"* - If you know what you're doing you can break any rule. The people behind glibc is extremely skilled programmers. Are you?

Comment: Another thing is that glibc is a core element. If it performs bad, the whole system performs bad. Everything needs to be optimized. So those behind glibc cannot really sacrifice performance for readability.

Comment: This is _not_ abuse. I do similar macros all the time. It is a [somewhat] advanced technique, but it is actually quite clean [as clean as it can be for C]. This technique is also used in the linux kernel.

Comment: @CraigEstey I realize that I was very unclear. I do not consider this abuse. I'm just saying that just because those who are the best of the best is using a certain technique does not mean it's a good idea for average Joe to use the same technique.

Comment: The use of macros may be the most efficient way to implement a type of 'generic' container in C - but this is a reckless use of namespaces - or lack thereof in this case. At the very least, publicly exposed macros should be prefixed with something like `GLIBC_`.  As a C library implementation, they would probably be justified in using a 'reserved' identifier like: `_GLIBC_` or `_LIBC_`, etc.

Comment: @klutt I think we're agreeing. My "not abuse" was directed at OP's comment [not yours]. We both agree that a beginner should be careful with this. As you say, "skilled programmers". Complex macros _are_ okay in C [the ones cited here are good examples]. IMO, it's only been some `c++` pgmrs that complain about macros. If the C compilers had been designed to routinely output the expanded text to a file [like other macro processors do, like `masm`], there would be much less seeming ire.

Comment: @BrettHale No, it's _not_ reckless because a user has to _explicitly_ do `#include <sys/queue.h>` so they _know_ they're doing this. It is _never_ implicitly pulled in from another `.h` (e.g. `stdio.h`). These macro names used are verbose enough without adding a prefix everywhere. If there _were_ a conflict somehow, this could handled by isolating the use of `sys/queue.h` to a specific `.c` (e.g. `mysysqueue.c`) and put the conflicts in another `.c` And, it's _not_ `glibc` specific. This is Berkeley BSD code (from 1994), so a better prefix might be `SYSQ_`

Comment: @CraigEstey - sorry, but it's flat-out bad practice. Have a look at the header dependency output of say, gcc's `-M` output for any non-trivial source code. Whether it's GNU or BSD code is entirely beside the point I was making.

Comment: @BrettHale I don't see what `-M` has to do with `sys/queue.h`. You either include it or you don't. It _only_ defines macros--it's 100% self contained. So, if you do the include, you _do_ get a source dependency on the file. But, what of it? Such usage does _not_ need a namespace. This is C, so what is a "namespace"? As many programmers here on SO are fond of saying _there is no such language as c/c++ -- pick one_ The biggest threat to C is "c++ feature creep".

Comment: @CraigEstey - this is such a colloquial term for naming conventions, reserved identifiers, etc., you can't seriously think this refers solely to the `namespace` feature of C++. I think you've demonstrated this is not an argument worth continuing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are these all defined as macros?

To allow them to work with any type - ie. to be "type generic".

```
struct my_int { int a; };
LIST_HEAD(list_of_my_ints, my_int);

struct my_struct { int a; double b; };
LIST_HEAD(list_of_my_structs, my_struct);
```

> Why all these macro type definitions in glibc?

This is an old/common (you may see on top `Copyright (c) 1991, 1993`) implementation of various linked list in C, it comes from BSD systems (I think). [FreeBSD man 3 queue](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=queue&sektion=3) has great documentation about them. But also see Linux man-pages [man 7 queue](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/queue.7.html).

> "Dont abuse the preprocessor" and yet here in glibc they have entire files definied that are nothing but extremely complicated macros.

C has no templates and implementing type-generic interfaces is a hard task. It's not perfect, C++ templates are way easier. When working in C, implementing a linked-list in C for the 1000nd time can be frustrating and it's just time consuming. To implement something type generic you can write a lot of function-pointer-ish interfaces or write them using macros that take the type as an argument. For an alternative implementation of a linked list in C you may see [list.h from linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h). From the other side - [g_list_* from Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html).

Comment: Another alternative implementation is the one used by the [Windows kernel and Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/singly-and-doubly-linked-lists).

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly "abusing" macros, but kind of what they are designed for.
C does not provide any way of writing type generic code. E.g.

```
struct {                                                                
        struct my_node *le_next;        /* next element */                        
        struct my_node **le_prev;        /* address of previous next element */      
}
```

would be a list entry only for `my_node`. Actually, many C developers have to reimplement the same data structures over and over again...

So if you have the macro for `LIST_HEAD(name, type)` and instantiate that with `LIST_HEAD(test_node_list, test_node)` you'll get the code

```
struct test_node_list {                                                                
        struct test_node *lh_first;        /* first element */                   
}
```

For better examples, see the man pages for [queue](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/queue.7.html) and at the bottom links to the specific ones, e.g., [list](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/list.3.html)